# sequelizejs beforeValidate getting keys and values into object

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get all fields and their corresponding values from a sequelize model in a beforeUpdate hook, but I cannot figure out my error

```
,{
    timestamps: false,
    underscored: true,
    hooks: {
      beforeValidate: function(transaction, options, fn) {
        var ObjectToHash = transaction.getDataValue(); // Here I'm trying to get only the fields and their values
        makehash(ObjectToHash)
        .then(function(res){
          transaction.hash = res;
          fn(null, transaction)
        })

      }
    }
  }
```

is getDataValue() the right function for that?

Answer (score -1):

Stupidity should be punishable ;)

```
beforeValidate: function(transaction, options, fn) {
        console.log('beforeCreate hook')
        var ObjectToHash = transaction.get();
        console.log(ObjectToHash)
        makehash(ObjectToHash)
        .then(function(res){
          console.log('hash created for: '+transaction.id)
          transaction.hash = res;
          fn(null, transaction)
        })

      }
```